# Can I place relay in a return wire?

Tags: ac, relay, solid-state-relay

Here is my scenario, I have a device that has two heating coils ( AC ) in parallel. The power wire is connected to the beginning of both heating coils and is can't easily be un-crimped. The returns are separate and meet at a wire nut. I want to isolate the larger coil and be able to turn it on and off with a relay, while leaving the smaller coil unaffected. Can I place a relay across the return wire somehow, so it only breaks the return of the larger coil? is the wrong way to do this?

Comment: You can put a relay across the return line although it makes no difference in AC.

Comment: You can put a relay contact IN the return wire (NOT "across" it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not place the relay "across" the return wire. You will switch the return wire with the relay contact.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8R63a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Switched neutral in low-powered heater element.*

This will work fine. Make sure your relay contacts current rating are greater current than the load current and that the voltage rating is greater than or equal to the supply voltage.

Comment: Great, one more question .... does the relay need to be grounded, was looking at this one https://www.amazon.com/5-12V-Module-Control-Optocoupler-Isolation/dp/B01LZ6F7LG/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1474401335&sr=8-10&keywords=12VDC+30+AMP+relay+board but the device does not have a ground wire

Comment: That's not a simple relay -  it's a relay and transistor driver module. It's intended for use with a 5 V micro-controller. GND connection is on the 5 V side and should be connected to the micro ground (or common or 0 V). The heater will use the two terminals on the other side of the module.